# Can I include groups to install in path dependencies with Poetry?

Tags: dependency-management, python-poetry, code-duplication

I have a Poetry project where I have a [path dependency](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies), which also is managed with Poetry. This path dependency has [optional groups](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-dependencies#optional-groups) which contain optional dependencies, and I would like to install one of these optional groups in the top-level project. However, I can't find any way to achieve apart from just copying the list of dependencies to the top-level project, which I would rather not do. Is there any way to achieve what I'd like to do with Poetry?